# Java Swing File and Folder Choose

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser

Hi I am new to swing and I need some help. I have build a file processing project where I read an input file and some other existing files in the project, do many checks and parsing and produce a csv and an xlsx file. Until now I used for these inputs

```
JTextField csvpath = new JTextField();
    JTextField csvfile = new JTextField();
    JTextField xmlpath = new JTextField();
    JTextField xmlfile = new JTextField();
    JTextField excpath = new JTextField();
    JTextField excfile = new JTextField();
    Object[] message = {
        "Enter the path of the CSV file to be created:", csvpath,
        "Enter the CSV file name:", csvfile,
        "Now enter the XML path to be read:", xmlpath,
        "Also enter the XML file name:", xmlfile,  
        "Please enter the Excel file path to be created:", excpath,
        "Finally enter the Excel file name:", excfile     
    };

    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Convert XML File to CSV File", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        String csvPath = csvpath.getText();
        String csvFileName = csvfile.getText();
        String xmlPath = xmlpath.getText();
        String xmlFileName = xmlfile.getText();
        String excPath = excpath.getText();
        String excFileName = excfile.getText();
        String FullcsvPath = csvPath + "\\" + csvFileName + ".csv";
        String FullxmlPath = xmlPath + "\\" + xmlFileName + ".xml";
        String excelPath = excPath + "\\" + excFileName + ".xlsx";
            .
            .
        parsing/creating starts...
```

Because in the future this project will be used by others I wanted to create file chooser and get the file/folder paths as strings in order to read the input and create etc...
I have created a class and public strings for paths and when I call it the program does not stop like before, continues to run while the Frame is open without getting the paths I want. My new class is:

```
public static void SelectFiles() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {

    final JFrame window = new JFrame("Parse for manufacturers - Developed by Aris M");
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel midPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel botPanel = new JPanel();
    final JButton openFolderChooser = new JButton("Select Folder to save csv - xlsx results");
    final JButton openFileChooser = new JButton("Select the File to be parsed");
    final JButton closeButton = new JButton("OK");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    openFolderChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("user.home"));
            fc.setDialogTitle("This is a JFileChooser");
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            if (fc.showOpenDialog(openFolderChooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                csv = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                xlsx = csv;
                System.out.println(csv);                    
            }                
        }
    });
    openFileChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("user.home"));
            fc.setDialogTitle("This is a JFileChooser");
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            if (fc.showOpenDialog(openFileChooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                xml = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println(xml);  
            }
        }
    });
    closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {   
                window.dispose();              
        }
    });
    window.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, topPanel);
    window.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, midPanel);
    window.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, botPanel);
    topPanel.add(openFolderChooser);
    midPanel.add(openFileChooser);
    botPanel.add(closeButton);
    window.setSize(500, 150);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);            
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "program does not stop like before" ?

Comment: How do you call the SelectFiles() method exactly ? I don't get the point of rendering a JFrame that way

Comment: @devmind with JOptionPane I can put the strings hit the ok button and then the program continues...

Comment: @SebVb Select_Files_Swing.SelectFiles(); inside the main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing code runs in separate thread known as the event dispatch thread. Just make your main thread busy while frame is visible. Add following code to the end of `SelectFiles()` method:

```
        while (window.isVisible()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```